# Ordenar datatable.net jquery por data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-datatables

Estou fazendo a ordenação da coluna ***PEDIDO*** assim:

```
"order": [[3, "asc"]]
```

Notem que a ordenação da colua ***PEDIDO*** **não** está correta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ordenação da coluna ***PEDIDO*** precisa ser assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O tipo do campo deve estar como `String`, note que está considerando apenas os primeiros dígitos. Deve converter para `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependendo da versão ou dos arquivos que você utiliza, ele não possua a extensão para ordenar por data.

Para alterar, basta adicionar o [DateTable date-euro](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-euro) em seu projeto e adicionar a coluna que deverá ser ordenada, exemplo:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
     columnDefs: [
       { type: 'date-euro', targets: 0 }
     ]
  });
```

Caso queira adicionar somente o código, o código da extensão é esse:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-euro-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x;

        if ( $.trim(a) !== '' ) {
            var frDatea = $.trim(a).split(' ');
            var frTimea = (undefined != frDatea[1]) ? frDatea[1].split(':') : [00,00,00];
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
        }
        else {
            x = Infinity;
        }

        return x;
    },

    "date-euro-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },

    "date-euro-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );
```

[Veja um exemplo no JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mvxLkz4r/45/)